ShadCN form updating the input field values manually
I am trying to build a form that shows a suggestion of serial numbers (data is fetched via an API and is happening correctly). I am able to get a suggestion of all serial numbers, however I dont understand how to chnage the value stored in the shadCN input field on clicking the suggested serial number.
the fetching and displaying is happening in the ProductInput component
The relevant code file is below:
import {
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { useFormContextServiceJob } from "@/app/_components/service-job-form/serviceJobFormProvider";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { componentsFetcher, productsFetcher } from "./itemsFetcher";
import { ComponentProps, ProductProps } from "@/next-auth";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { Components } from "./components";

const ProductInput = ({
    user,
    prodIndex,
    id,
    keyVal,
    remove,
}: {
    user: Session;
    prodIndex: number;
    id: string;
    keyVal: string;
    remove: any;
}) => {
    const { control, watch, register } = useFormContextServiceJob();
    const { fields, update } = useFieldArray({
        name: `products`,
        control,
        // rules: {
        //  minLength: ind,
        // },
    });

    const currData = watch();

    const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductProps[] | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(null);
    }, []);

    let debounceTime: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;
    const debounce = (fetchSuggestions: any, delay: number) => {
        return (...args: any[]) => {
            clearTimeout(debounceTime);
            debounceTime = setTimeout(() => fetchSuggestions(...args), delay);
        };
    };

    const handleInputChange = debounce((query: string) => {
        fetchSuggestions(query);
    }, 300);

    const fetchSuggestions = async (query: string) => {
        try {
            const data = await productsFetcher(
                user.user.access_token as string,
                query
            );
            console.log("Data of query: ", query, " is: ");
            console.log(data);

            if (data.length) setProducts(() => data);
            else throw new Error("");
        } catch (e: any) {
            setProducts(null);
        }
    };

    const setSelectedProduct = (val: { productId: string; serialNo: string }) => {
        const { serialNo } = val;
        update(prodIndex, {
            serialNo,
            components: [],
        });
        setProducts(null);
        // fields[prodIndex].serialNo = serialNo;
        // document.getElementsByClassName(`inputfield`)[prodIndex].value = serialNo;

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Current data is: ", currData);
            console.log("NEW state: ", fields);
        }, 2000);
    };

    console.log("CURR DATA IS HEHEHE: ", currData);
    console.log("CURR FILED IS HEHEHE: ", fields);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            !(
                products &&
                products.length === 1 &&
                currData.products[prodIndex].serialNo === products[0].serialNo
            )
        )
            handleInputChange(currData.products[prodIndex].serialNo);
        else setProducts(() => null);
    }, [currData?.products[prodIndex]?.serialNo]);

    return (
        <div key={keyVal}>
            <FormField
                control={control}
                name={`products.${prodIndex}.serialNo`}
                render={({ field, fieldState }) => {
                    console.log("FIELDDDD: ", field);
                    return (
                        <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel className="bg-green-400 px-3 py-1 rounded-lg">
                                Product {prodIndex + 1}
                            </FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                                <div className="relative">
                                    <Input
                                        placeholder="Serial Number"
                                        type="text"
                                        {...register(`products.${prodIndex}`)}
                                        {...field}
                                        onChangeCapture={(e) => {
                                            console.log(e);
                                        }}
                                        className="inputfield"
                                    />
                                    <Button
                                        className="absolute right-0 top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 scale-95 transition-all duration-150 hover:scale-90 active:scale-75 w-20 sm:w-44"
                                        onClick={() => remove(prodIndex)}
                                        variant={"destructive"}
                                    >
                                        <h1 className="text-ellipsis overflow-hidden">
                                            Remove Product
                                        </h1>
                                    </Button>
                                </div>
                            </FormControl>
                            <div>
                                {products &&
                                    products.length &&
                                    products.map((item, ind) => (
                                        <div
                                            key={ind}
                                            className="w-full py-3 bg-white px-2 text-lg rounded-lg text-ellipsis overflow-hidden text-nowrap cursor-pointer hover:scale-95 active:scale-90 transition-all duration-200"
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                field.value = item.serialNo;
                                                console.log("field: ", field.value);

                                                setSelectedProduct(item);
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            {item.serialNo}
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                            </div>
                        </FormItem>
                    );
                }}
            />
            <Components
                prodId={currData.products[prodIndex].serialNo}
                prodIndex={prodIndex}
                id={id}
                user={user}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export const Products = ({
    id,
    ind,
    user,
}: {
    id: string;
    ind: number;
    user: Session;
}) => {
    const { control } = useFormContextServiceJob();
    const { append, fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
        name: `products`,
        control,
        // rules: {
        //  minLength: ind,
        // },
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {fields.map((product, prodIndex) => (
                <ProductInput
                    keyVal={product.id}
                    user={user}
                    prodIndex={prodIndex}
                    id={id}
                    key={product.id}
                    remove={remove}
                />
            ))}
            <div>
                <Button
                    className="scale-95 transition-all duration-150 hover:scale-90 active:scale-75 w-20 sm:w-44 mt-5 bg-orange-400"
                    onClick={() => {
                        append({ serialNo: "", components: [] });
                    }}
                >
                    <h1 className="text-ellipsis overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap">
                        Add new Product
                    </h1>
                </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};


I tried to set the field.value = serialNo (field from the FormField of shadCN), but it doesn't update the input text box
